# Find an upper bound for $f(x) = \sin(\sin(x))$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've run into this hard calculus problem that I can't seem to solve.  The question is:

> If $f(x) = \sin(\sin x)$, use a graph to find an upper bound for $|f^{(iv)}(x)|$.

I am not sure what I have to do.  Should I find the fourth derivative and then find the maximum of that graph.  Or do I have to do something completely different?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It certainly is difficult to analyze the fourth derivative from the graph of the original function. Your suggestion seems to be the best one. Could you ask your teacher what the question means?

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, $\frac{\mathsf d^4}{\mathsf d^4x}f(x) = -3\sin^2 x\sin(\sin x)) + \sin(\sin x))\cos^4 x + 6\sin x\cos^2 x\cos(\sin x)) + 4\sin(\sin x))\cos^2 x +\sin x\cos(\sin x))$ I really hope your teacher doesn't expect you to compute that by hand...

Comment: Using a grapher, $|f^{(iv)}(x)|<4$, but this problem statement looks improbable.

Comment: @Math1000 Yeah this professor is known for giving absurdly tedious problems.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3554599 then you are justified in giving him absurd answers. But it is safer to use a computer.

Comment: My guess is that a clever use of Taylor's theorem will yield the desired, but I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem in that way.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To solve the problem, I agree with you that you must find the 4th derivative of the given functio then graph it using any graphing tools. But this is tedious. However, you can use Wolfram Alpha To help you on answering your problem. Wolfram Alpha gives the result below for the 4th derivative of $f$ ogether with the graph:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

NOW, with extended search using Wolfram Alpha we have found the upperbound to be:3.76783

[image]